# Data accessing by any components of angular 5 application. Data is being set via a API call inside auth service

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-services, angular-services, angular-components

I have a shared auth service which is injected by all components in my angular 5 application . I have few variables in my auth service . i am calling a api inside auth service and setting the response value to the variables. Now i want to access the value of these variables from any component any time from my application.I don not want to use local storage or session storage.

Answer (score 0):

I find that when dealing with HTTP calls it's easier to reason about things using promises - so I'll give you a solution using promises.

```
class UserService {
    private userData;
    private userDataPromise;

    getUserData(...){
        if(this.userData){
            return Promise.resolve(this.userData); //if we have the data, just return it
        }

        if(this.userDataPromise){
            // in case the call to the api is in progress, we don't want to make a new one.
            return this.userDataPromise;
        }

        this.userDataPromise = this.http.get(...).toPromise()
                                   .then((data) => this.userData = data)
                                   .finally(() => this.userDataPromise = undefined);
        return this.userDataPromise;
    }
}
```

It will be up to you to reset the data once the user is logged out for example.

HTH